# Looking for a way to Remove a String from ArrayList by only finding a part of the String

Tags: java

I want to remove this whole single input by just having the user type in the Lisence Plate Number which would be a unique number.

The String would print out something like "Car Ford F1 LC4PR0 Black"

Is there a way to find "LC4PR0" only and delete this whole String?

````
public static void Add_Vehicle(ArrayList<String> list){

        int listsize = list.size();

        if(listsize == 50){
            System.out.println("Vehicle Garage Full! 50/50 Vehicles");
        }
        else{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Type. Car/Motorbike");
            String VehicleType = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();




            if(VehicleType.equals("CAR")){
                String VehicleCar = "Car";

                System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Make");
                String CarMake = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Model");
                String CarModel = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Lisence Plate.");
                String CarPlate = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Colour");
                String CarColour = input.nextLine();

                String CarDetails = VehicleCar + " " + CarMake + " " + CarModel + " " + CarPlate + " " + CarColour;

                list.add(CarDetails);
        }
            else if(VehicleType.equals("MOTORBIKE")){
                String VehicleMotorbike = "Car";

                System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Make");
                String MotorbikeMake = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Model");
                String MotorbikeModel = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Lisence Plate.");
                String MotorbikePlate = input.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Vehicle Colour");
                String MotorbikeColour = input.nextLine();

                String MotorbikeDetails = VehicleMotorbike + " " + MotorbikeMake + " " + MotorbikeModel + " " + MotorbikePlate + " " + MotorbikeColour;

                list.add(MotorbikeDetails);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please Only Enter Vehicle Type, Car or Motorbike!");
        }
            Menu(list);
        }

    }```
````

Comment: `list.removeIf(s -> s.contains("LC4PR0"));`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific pattern of License Plate you can use regex to find all the ocurrence.

Comment: What regex? Use OP's example and create this regex, along with an explanation.

Comment: Why? A simple `String#contains(...)` ought to suffice

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#split(String)`.

Split slice string to string array with parameter.

As example, `"test test2 test3".split(" ")` returns `{"test","test2","test3"}`.

See code below.

Java 7

```
public String search(String target){
  for(String n : list){
    String[] split = n.split(" ");
    if(split[3].equals(target)){
      return split[3]; // Return n if you want to return all string
  }
  // Cannot find target
  return null;
}
```

Java 8

```
public String search(String str){
  List<String> lst = list.filter(s -> s.split(" ")[3].equals(str)).collect(Collectors.toList());
  return lst.size() == 0 ? null : lst.get(0).split(" ")[3]; // Do not split if you want to return all string
}
```